# Passing variable into AsyncHttpResponseHandler callback for Android

Tags: java, android, android-async-http

I am using the AsyncHttpResponseHandler to gather data from a RESTful service.  The problem I am encountering is that I can not access a variable I need in the onSuccess callback.

My code is as follows.

```
for (int i=0; i<=count; i++) {
        requestItemsByCategory(context, categories.get(i), 10, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                loadItemsFromJsonString(context, response, categories.get(i));
            }
        });
    }
```

The context and the categories are not available in the onSuccess obviously.  I could make these global variables, but the issue would be that this is getting calle din a loop, so the onSuccess will be called a few times with no guarantee which one returns first.

I am pretty new to Java.  In Objetive-C, you stil have access to the variables outside of the anonymous function inside the code block.  If it can't be done, I will jsut have to customize my query to pull back all the data at once, and then parse it on the client-side, which is a better solution anyway, but I would like to know if accessing items inside the callback is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you cannot access these variable in this scope however you could try to access them through the instance of the class this code is:

```
class YourCoolActivity extends Activity {

  // + getter/setter
  private int index;

  // The rest of the class

 private void yourCoolMethod(){
    for (int i=0; i<=count; i++) {
      this.setIndex(categories.get(i));
      requestItemsByCategory(this.getContext(), categories.get(i), 10, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(String response) {
              loadItemsFromJsonString(YourCoolActivity.this.getContext(), response, YourCoolActivity.this.getIndex());
          }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an anonymous inner class you could create a simple new class that takes as parameters to the constructor the values you want to access in the onSuccess method.

```
class MyResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    private Context context;
    private Category category;
    public MyResponseHandler( Context context, Category category ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.category = category;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess( String response ) {
        loadItemsFromJsonString(context, response, category);
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes

```
for (int i=0; i<=count; i++) {
    requestItemsByCategory(context, categories.get(i), 10, new MyResponseHandler(context, categories.get(i));
}
```